# How to allow access to kubernetes api using egress network policy?

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Init container with `kubectl get pod` command is used to get ready status of other pod.

After Egress NetworkPolicy was turned on init container can't access Kubernetes API: `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout`. CNI is Calico.

Several rules were tried but none of them are working (service and master host IPs, different CIDR masks):

```
...
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.96.0.1/32
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
...
```

or using namespace (default and kube-system namespaces):

```
...
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: default
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
...
```

Looks like `ipBlock` rules just don't work and namespace rules don't work because kubernetes api is non-standard pod.

Can it be configured? Kubernetes is 1.9.5, Calico is 3.1.1.

Problem still exists with GKE 1.13.7-gke.8 and calico 3.2.7

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Same issue on GKE `1.11.6-gke.3` (using Calico `v3.2.4`)

Comment: Did you label your `default` namespace with label `name=default`? For me it wasn't obvious that namespace required labeling - I learned it from [TGI Kubernetes 085: Network Policies](https://youtu.be/gzzq7TGBsL8)

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck I tried everything. using CIDR, labels.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to get the real ip of the master using `kubectl get endpoints --namespace default kubernetes` and make an egress policy to allow that.

```
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
metadata:
  name: allow-apiserver
  namespace: test
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: x.x.x.x/32
```

Comment: Is it possible for the master's IP to change? If so, this configuration may break when it does.

Comment: Make sure that you are also using the correct port. The 443 port used inside the pod may have been changed outside the pod to something like 4443. `get endpoints --namespace default kubernetes -o wide` lists the IP address + port.

Comment: This works but I'm a bit skeptical about if this will potentially break if IP updates. In which case for a less strict range you can use `cidr: 10.0.0.0/8` to allow access generally inside the cluster

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue when using ciliumnetworkpolicy with helm. For anyone having a similar issue, something like this should work:

```yaml
{{- $kubernetesEndpoint := lookup "v1" "Endpoints" "default" "kubernetes" -}}
{{- $kubernetesAddress := (first $kubernetesEndpoint.subsets).addresses -}}
{{- $kubernetesIP := (first $kubernetesAddress).ip -}}
apiVersion: cilium.io/v2
kind: CiliumNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  egress:
    - toCIDRSet:
        - cidr: {{ $kubernetesIP }}/32
    ...
```

Comment: `toEntities: [ kube-apiserver ]` – no need to look up the IP range if you can use the built-in functionality. Only works for Cilium.

Answer (score 0):

We aren't on GCP, but the same should apply.

We query AWS for the CIDR of our master nodes and use this data as values for helm charts creating the NetworkPolicy for the k8s API access.

In our case the masters are part of an auto-scaling group, so we need the CIDR. In your case the IP might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow egress traffic to the Kubernetes API endpoints IPs and ports.

You can get the endpoints by running `$ kubectl get endpoints kubernetes -oyaml`.

I don't understand why it doesn't work to just allow traffic to the cluster IP of the `kubernetes` service in the `default` namespace (what is in the `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT` env vars), but anyway, it works to allow traffic to the underlying endpoints.

To do this in a Helm chart template, you could do something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  podSelector: ...
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    {{- range (lookup "v1" "Endpoints" "default" "kubernetes").subsets }}
    - to:
        {{- range .addresses }}
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: {{ .ip }}/32
        {{- end }}
      ports:
        {{- range .ports }}
        - protocol: {{ .protocol }}
          port: {{ .port }}
        {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```