# Calico's network policy can't select kubernetes.default service

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy, google-spark-operator

I'm using [google spark-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) and some [calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/networkpolicy#rule) network policies to protect the namespaces.

The Spark driver pods need to be able to communicate with the `kubernetes` service in the `default` namespace to speak with the api-server.
This is what I get :

```
Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [xx]  in namespace: [xx]  failed.
```

***The problem is :**

Using any kind of network policies blocks communication toward the default namespace. Restoring the connectivity is possible but selecting the `kubernetes.default` service is still impossible as it is a particular service (has no selectors)... And so you can't communicate with it !*

---

I tried opening communication to all pods in `default` + `kube-system` namespace. It's working for all services **except** `kubernetes.default` which is still unreachable !

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: mynetpol
spec:
  selector: all()
  types:
    - Egress
  egress:

    # Allows comm to kube-system namespace
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        selector: all()
        namespaceSelector: ns == 'kube-system'
    - action: Allow
      source:
        selector: all()
        namespaceSelector: ns == 'kube-system'

   # Allows comm to default namespace
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        selector: all()
        namespaceSelector: ns == 'default'
    - action: Allow
      source:
        selector: all()
        namespaceSelector: ns == 'default'
```

For some reasons curling `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443` timeouts event though all communication is wide open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... In the end...

Network policies don't work on services that dont target pods, which is the case of this particular `kubernetes` service sitting quietly in the `default` namespace. It's a special service that always points to the api-server.

---

The solution is to retrieve the api-server's real IP and allow `egress`-ing to it.

To find this IP you can use this command :

```
kubectl get endpoints --namespace default kubernetes
```

*Courtesy of @Dave McNeill*

Then you can allow this IP in you network policy.

- If you are using the default netpol API, check Dave's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56494510/5512455
- If you are using the calico policies, which I encourage you to do because the Kube ones sucks, following is the working yaml:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-api-server
spec:
  selector: all()
  types:
    - Egress
  egress:

    # Allow api-server
    - action: Allow
      protocol: TCP
      destination:
        nets:
        - <Your api-server IP>/32
        ports:
        - 6443
```